# c# cross thread error

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

i wrote a program that saves 3 different positions of my sensor. I want the backroundcolor of my textboxes green if the Sensor is back in the saved position. Becaus the values are changing realy fast and precise i decided just to compare the first 3 values. So i started my program and saved a position by clicking. The position is saved and the textboxes are immediatley green which is fine because the Sensor is still in this position. But after that i get an exception for cross threading and i dont understand it. Im new into C# and i thougt i solved this problem with the invokes at the beginning of my function.

```
        private void Safe_Position1(TextBox tBr1, TextBox tBi1, TextBox tBj1, TextBox tBk1, string[] text)
    {
        if (button3clicked == true)
        {
            if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                textBox5.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Safe_Position1(tBr1, tBi1, tBj1, tBk1, text)));
            }
            if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                textBox7.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Safe_Position1(tBr1, tBi1, tBj1, tBk1, text)));
            }
            if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                textBox8.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Safe_Position1(tBr1, tBi1, tBj1, tBk1, text)));
            }
            if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                textBox9.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Safe_Position1(tBr1, tBi1, tBj1, tBk1, text)));
            }

            else
            {
                tBr1.Text = text[0];
                tBi1.Text = text[1];
                tBj1.Text = text[2];
                tBk1.Text = text[3];
                button3clicked = false;
            }

            string firstthreetBr1 = new string(text[0].Take(3).ToArray());
            string firstthreetBi1 = new string(text[1].Take(3).ToArray());
            string firstthreetBj1 = new string(text[2].Take(3).ToArray());
            string firstthreetBk1 = new string(text[3].Take(3).ToArray());


            if (firstthreetBr1 == tBr1.Text.Substring(0,3)) <------ EXCEPTION HERE
            {
                tBr1.Background = Brushes.Green;
            }
            if (firstthreetBi1 == tBi1.Text.Substring(0, 3))
            {
                tBi1.Background = Brushes.Green;
            }
            if (firstthreetBj1 == tBj1.Text.Substring(0, 3))
            {
                tBj1.Background = Brushes.Green;
            }
            if (firstthreetBk1 == tBk1.Text.Substring(0, 3))
            {
                tBk1.Background = Brushes.Green;
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: What exception?

Comment: And on which line?

Comment: Safe vs Save vs Safe

Comment: Each of your `BeginInvoke()` blocks needs a `return` otherwise after calling `BeginInvoke()` the code following the `if`s will still be excecuted.

Comment: What is exception message

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Comment: You are accessing a UI element from a non-UI thread with the call to `tBr1.Text`. You can't do that. All access to UI elements must be done on the UI thread. Stop with all of the `Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` calls - do it once and make sure that you're running your code on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have made similar (not the same - you should understand not copy paste) situation for you.

on button click I am creating 3 threads which are updating text of Textboxes (which were created in UI thread)

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() => ThreadRunner(1));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() => ThreadRunner(2));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(() => ThreadRunner(3));
    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();
    t3.Start();
}
private void ThreadRunner(int threadNum)
{
    while(true)
    {
        TextBoxUpdater(threadNum);
        Thread.Sleep(100 * threadNum);
    }
}
```

and method which is being called to update textboxes,

```
private void TextBoxUpdater(int num)
{
    //here i m checking, if it is from different thread then UI thread
    //if yes then Invoke is used, 
    //      so it will call the same method but in UI thread
    if(this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        txtBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => TextBoxUpdater(num)));
        txtBox2.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => TextBoxUpdater(num)));
        txtBox3.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => TextBoxUpdater(num)));
    }
    else
    {
        //If it is UI thread (meaning this call is coming from If part of this method)
        //and as it is UI thread now, we can update textbox's text
        txtBox1.Text = num.ToString();
        txtBox2.Text = num.ToString();
        txtBox3.Text = num.ToString();
    }

    //but after all above checks, we are leving below code without any checking
    //so once if part of this code will call this function again and else part of code runs
    // and then after completing that call, 
    //      flow will retun back to if part (not that it is not UI thread), 
    //      then flow will directly checks below codition and throw an exception
    if (txtBox1.Text.Substring(1) == "1")
    {

    }
}
```

with minimum changes you can do it like below to prevent exception.

```
private void TextBoxUpdater(int num)
{
    //here i m checking, if it is from different thread then UI thread
    //if yes then Invoke is used, 
    //      so it will call the same method but in UI thread
    if(this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        txtBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => TextBoxUpdater(num)));
        txtBox2.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => TextBoxUpdater(num)));
        txtBox3.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => TextBoxUpdater(num)));
    }
    else
    {
        //If it is UI thread (meaning this call is coming from If part of this method)
        //and as it is UI thread now, we can update textbox's text
        txtBox1.Text = num.ToString();
        txtBox2.Text = num.ToString();
        txtBox3.Text = num.ToString();

        //perform this logic too insdie of else block
        if (txtBox1.Text.Substring(1) == "1")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

But then too, your method will end up calling too many unnecessary calls to `TextBoxUpdater` . **you should wonder why I'm stating this.**

so to fix this part, you should modify your method like below.

```
private void TextBoxUpdater(int num)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        //if current call is form other than UI thread invoke to UI thread
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => TextBoxUpdater(num)));
    }
    else
    {
        //If it is UI thread (meaning this call is coming from If part of this method)
        //and as it is UI thread now, we can update textbox's text
        txtBox1.Text = num.ToString();
        txtBox2.Text = num.ToString();
        txtBox3.Text = num.ToString();
        if (txtBox1.Text.Substring(1) == "1")
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As Matthew has commented You have to write return statement after every BeginInvoke(). This code throws an exception because after Your method returns from BeginInvoke() it goes deeper into the code.